# How to write the code for 'addToRightMostChildAsLeftChild(Node a,Node b)'?

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal

Lets say the above method has two arguments `a and b`:

- **a** : represents the root node  of the tree for which we need to traverse till we get the right node
- **b** : represents the node to be added to a's right most node as a left child.

I just need to know how to add a `node to the *right most node* of the tree but as a *left child*. I'm actually solving a different version of [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modify-binary-tree-get-preorder-traversal-using-right-pointers/#comment-4419662162) problem. Here the problem is using *right pointers*.

Construct a tree in such a way that traversing it only through left pointers generates **pre-order traversal** of the tree.

Actually it can be solved by traversing the tree and maintaining a `previous node and linking them in the way we want :`prev.left = current`.

**My way of approaching this problem was:**
If there's a tree as following

(just add the node 2 to 5 as a left child
and then 5 to 3 as left child and finally 6 to 4 as left child.)

```
                 10
                 / \
                8   2
               / \ / \
              3  5 4  6


               10
               /
              8
             / \
            3   5
               /
              2
             / \
            4   6

             10
             /
            8
           / 
          3
         /
        5
       /
      2 
     / \
    4   6
             10
             /
            8
           / 
          3
         /
        5
       /
      2
     /
    4
   /
  6
```

10 8 3 5 2 4 6 which is the `pre-order traversal` of the tree

I know it can be done by using `prev pointer and doing stuff. I want it do be done this way.

```
                 10        
                 / \
                8   2      
               / \ / \
              3  5 4  6

                 ||
                 \/

                10
               /
              8
             / 
            3
           /
          5
         /
        2
       /
      4
     /
    6
```

**Node is defined as:**

```
 class Node{
    int data;
    Node left,right;
    Node(int d)
    {
        data=d;
        left=null;
        right=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which language ?

Comment: @ZainArshad Its in Java

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: void addToEnd(Node  a, Node  b){
    if(a.right==null)
        a.right = b;
    else
        addToEnd(a.right, b) ;
} //I have tried to add it at the end but as a right child

Comment: well, i was just coding it ... hahahaa glad that you solved it .. you can share the solution in the answer !

Comment: You can paste it on comments .. i'll answer it so that in future if someone has same problem it can take advantage from your question.. thats how "SO" works

Comment: @ZainArshad yeah sure. Acutally I'm new to SO.

Answer (score 1):

After giving it some thought I am able to do it.

```
void addToRightMostNodeAsLeftChild(Node root,Node toBeAdded)
{
    if(root.left==null)
    {
        root.left=toBeAdded;
    }
    else
    {
        Node k=getRMNode(root.left);
        if(k.left==null)
        {
            k.left=toBeAdded;
        }
        else
            addToRightMostNodeAsLeftChild(k, toBeAdded);
    }
    root.right=null;
}
```

So, When I want to place node 2 as a **left child** of 5 which is the **right-most node** of node 8 (adding as a left child to the right most node of some XYZ node XYZ being 8 here )
When the method is called as follows:

```
addToRightMostNodeAsLeftChild(root,X) /*root represents node 10 and X represents node 2*/
```

it gets converted to:

```
           10
           /
          8
         / \
        3   5
           /
          2
         / \
        4   6
```